How to connect a STM32F4xxxRE on a custom PCB
This is the first time I've designed a PCB with a STM32. I found a PDF on the internet that gives me an example of a Nucleo connection (STM32 Nucleo-64 schematics), but I'm not sure if my schematic is correct.
I don't need all the headers or the USB connection (I'll be using ST-LINK v2).
Here's a screenshot of my MCU schematic and my power supply schematic.

Updated the schematic with red circule

Can anyone tell me if this is correct or if I need to add or remove components and where?

Nobody can tell you what you need unless you tell everybody what you need to achieve.

My project is to control dc motors with this MCU, i just need to be sure that the MCU is correctly powered and the STLINK connexion is correct to flash the MCU after witht the software CUBEIDE from ST

I don't have time to go into detail about everything that needs to change, but at the very least, reconsider what you're doing with the Zener diode, don't connect VBAT to something that could be greater than 3.6V, and add a pull-up on NRST. Also consider how you're going to connect the DC motor controller(s) to the MCU. Right now, I don't see any GPIO connections that could be used for that sort of thing.

Hello Ryan, i have updated the schematic and the screenshot please can you give me a feedback please. Regarding the dc control i dont  put the gpio yet but its not a big deal.

No, it is not correct. AVDD, VBAT and VCAP are all unconnected. So is BOOT0 and NRST. And JTAG pinout, it will not work with standard SWD adapter. For some reason your bypass caps are 100nF electrolytics, and no suggested larger bulk cap.
You should read the diagrams in the:
a) datasheet for that MCU, it has a diagram how to power it
b) hardware getting started appnote which also tells how to power it
c) Nucleo schematic which gives an actual example how to power it.

I updated the schematic can you take a look please

@Paulo971 What should I look at? It still does not match the recommendations in the datasheet for power bypassing. Also PA2/PA3 is an UART but not an UART capable of firmware update. Speaking of which the BOOT1 pin is floating, but if you are never using the bootoader, it does not matter. The JTAG connector is large and could contain the rest of the JTAG pins, not just SWD, but it will work. Generally it is not a great idea to short capacitors with pushbuttons, but many peope do it anyway.
